# Windows Store Apps : suppress "Common" folder generation?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm writing a Windows Store app, and I'd like to know if it's possible to suppress the generation of the "Common" folder, containing the code from Microsoft, which - imho I do not need.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Common contains StandardStyles.xaml which per App.xaml:

```
<!-- 
  Styles that define common aspects of the platform look and feel
  Required by Visual Studio project and item templates
-->
<ResourceDictionary Source="Common/StandardStyles.xaml"/>
```

and in StandardStyles.xaml:

```
<!--
    This file contains XAML styles that simplify application development.

    These are not merely convenient, but are required by most Visual Studio project and item templates.
    Removing, renaming, or otherwise modifying the content of these files may result in a project that
    does not build, or that will not build once additional pages are added.  If variations on these
    styles are desired it is recommended that you copy the content under a new name and modify your
    private copy.
-->
```

That said if you've determined it's not something you'll need just delete it, simpler and less fragile than hacking a T4 template (or whatever mechanism is used) for the code generation.

Comment: thing is, I'm creating a modular application and in each of my module-assembiles I'm having this folder generated. It's annoying. Why have N times the Common folder, instead of the same thing at a single location? All I'm looking for is the option to suppress it's generation :)

Comment: your getting a Common for project types other than the main application?  like for Class Library or Windows Runtime Component?  I feel like I'm missing something here.

Comment: Yes, I'm having it generated in a Class Library for Windows Store apps , when adding a "Page" item

Comment: if you're getting it in a Class Library, you're getting a number of classes as well that are essential to the operation of the page class (note, a Blank Page doesn't bring in the Common folder). Each library is a unit, but if you have pages in different libraries and they don't have require different implementations in Common, why not just use a Basic Page and change the class in inherits from Page to LayoutAwarePage scoped to the assembly which contains your one instance of Common files?  I see what you are saying, but seems sort of a 10% case and not hard to overcome?